# Excel Solver - constraint with variable range of cells

Tags: vba, excel, solver

I'm doing a macro in Excel that solves an exercise in Solver. My problem is that the number of variables that form the constraints are variable.
That is, I have in the sheet "Results" my target cell and my cells to vary. The number of cells to be varied is variable, starting in cell AF22 and ending in cell AF & var11. Similarly, the row of the target cell can also be variable, being in column AH and row var2.
The restrictions are that cells AG22: AG & var11 are the same as other cells in the sheet "Input data": F31: F & var2.
When I run the macro I get the error: "Error in the model, check that all the cells and constraints are valid."
I put the macro so that it is better understood:

```
var2 = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Val(30), Sheets("Input data").Range("G28").Value)
var11 = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Val(21), Sheets("Input data").Range("G28").Value)
var12 = var11 + Val(4)
'
'SOLVER
Sheets("Results").Select
Range(Cells(22, 32), Cells(var11, 32)).Select
Selection.ClearContents
'Objetivo
SolverReset
SolverOk SetCell:=Sheets("Results").Cells(var12, 34), MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=Sheets("Results").Range(Sheets("Results").Cells(22, 32), Sheets("Resultados válvula").Cells(var11, 32)), Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG NonLinear"

'Constraints
Set rang = Sheets("Results").Range(Sheets("Results").Cells(22, 33), Sheets("Results").Cells(var11, 33))
Set const = Sheets("Input data").Range(Sheets("Input data").Cells(31, 6), Sheets("Input data").Cells(var2, 6))
    SolverAdd CellRef:=rang.Address, Relation:=2, FormulaText:=const.Address
SolverSolve
```

Can anyone help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Not used Solver much so don't know, but when I record a macro I get `SolverOk SetCell:="$A$1", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:="0", ByChange:="$C$1:$C$2"` which suggests the first and last parameters need to be passed as addresses rather than ranges?

Comment: @SJR Like this? `Set cell = Sheets("Resultados válvula").Cells(var12, 34)
Set variab = Sheets("Resultados válvula").Range(Sheets("Resultados válvula").Cells(22, 32), Sheets("Resultados válvula").Cells(var11, 32))
  SolverOk SetCell:=cell.Address, MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=variab.Address, Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG NonLinear"  `  It doesn't work either.

Comment: Also, all the information you pass to solver needs to reside on the same sheet. You have some on "Input Data" and some on "Results".

Comment: Thank you so much @OldUgly, I changed my restrictions to the sheet "Results" and it worked!